# Adding Path in GIT for KIVY

Tags: python, git, kivy

Create a ﬁle named 'py.ini' and place it either in your users application data directory, or in 'C:\Windows'. It will contain the path used to start Kivy. 
I put my Kivy installation at 'C:\utils\kivy'
so my copy says:

[commands]
kivy="c:\utils\kivy\kivy.bat"

(You could also add commands to start other script interpreters, such as jython or IronPython.)

---

so my question is:

What commands are supposed to be used in GIT to add this path into a variable "kivy".

Or is it even suppose to be a variable?

And in GIT, to get the script working, it uses "source /c/.../Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32/kivyenv.sh"

But, on to add path, they said to use "C:...\kivy.bat

Why does " /c/" change to "C:"
and why is it 'kivy.ba't not 'kivyenv.sh'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This value is not typically something you would include in a git repo because it is specific to your system. Other people using your repo may have Kivy installed somewhere else, or be on an entirely different OS where that path does not exist.